# How do I properly structure self-invoking nested functions within the larger picture of a namespaced application?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can create a self-invoking, nested function like this

```
(function ns(){

    (function Class(){

        alert('ns.Class fired');

    })();

})();​
```

But it's ugly, and doesn't look quite right.

My [js](/questions/tagged/js) chops aren't what they should be, and I'm hoping someone can show me a better way to structure my namespaced app and still be able to utilize "some" self invoking functions.

```
// THIS DOESN'T WORK
//     because I haven't called "ns"
function ns(){

    (function Class(){

        alert('fired');

    })();

};​
```

For my purposes, the reason I'm asking this is to better namespace my JS in conjunction with jQuery.

So I'd like to be able to do something like this (which DOES WORK)

```
var ns = ns || {};
ns.Class = function(){};

ns.Class.Navigation = (function() {

    $('#element').on('click', function() {alert('element clicked');});

})();​
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right way to structure larger (read: js heavy) apps?!?!

- Is the weight of this too heavy?
- Is there a smarter way to achieve this?

Comment: it appears as though subtle curses are only allowed in source and not in question text: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shit (see the edit history for context)

Comment: None of these functions are "self-invoking" (e.g. recursive), they're just invoked immediately after definition. Your examples do not fire because they are not executed!

Comment: obviously that's the case. I was giving reference to what **doesn't** work.

Comment: There's no issue here other than *"I don't like it"*. I could post questions all day that say *"I don't like this..."*, and give an answer stating *"I like this better..."*. But there would be no point to doing that.

Comment: What is it, specifically, that you don't like? This is a well-established JS idiom for using a function only for scoping. Anything else will make your ultimate intention less clear to other developers.

Comment: If your specific use case is a jQuery plugin, consider perusing [this long article of jQuery plugin module patterns](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/) for one that fits.

Comment: @FrancisAvila in my first example, it just looks bloated and cluttered. In my head, it just doesn't look right. My second example look more right, but I'm still concerned that it might be too heavy.  At the end of the day, I just want to being on the right path before the JS in my app gets gigantic and unmanageable.

Comment: The only difference between your first and second example is the invocation. You can get the second example to work by adding `ns()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, First off: the fact that your calling the "main" IIFE `ns` suggests that you think of it as a namespace object, which isn't entirely correct. Namespaces are often created using IIFE's because they have the added benefit of closure scope(s). But in the end, namespaces are just a fancy word for Object (literals). 
Take the most popular lib/toolkit/framework out there: jQuery. Basically, it's one huge IIFE, that constructs an equally vast object, that is assigned a number of methods and properties (well, references to function objects anyway). There are some other objects and variables created in that IIFE, but they are either not *exposed* to the global object at all, or (Very) indirectly.

Allow me to clarify:

```
var myNameSpace = (function()
{
    var invisibleVar = 'can\'t touch this';
    var objectLiteral = {sing: function()
        {
            return invisibleVar;//exposed, albeit indirectly
        },
        property: 'Hammertime'
    };
    var semiExposed;
    objectLiteral.getSemi = function(newVal)
    {
        return semiExposed;//change closure var
    };
    objectLiteral.changeSemi = function(newVal)
    {
        semiExposed = newVal;//change closure var
    };
    objectLiteral.restoreSemi = (function(initVal)
    {
        return function()
        {
            semiExposed = initVal;//restore to value set when main IIFE was executed
            //don't worry about what this references: use the force... of the scope
            return objectLiteral.getSemi();//<-- return init val
        };
    }(semiExposed));//pass initial value to this scope
    var notExposedAtAll = function()
    {//can't be called but inside the main IIFE scope (and subsequent scopes)
        objectLiteral.foo = 'But it adds a public property';
    };
    objectLiteral.changeMe = function()
    {
        notExposedAtAll();//called in default context (either null or global, but it doesn't matter here)
    };
    return objectLiteral;//direct exposure
}());
```

This uses some of the basic principals all toolkits/libs, and actually all decent JS scripts share: using functions as first class object, using them as expressions to create a temporary scope etc...) 
IMO, it makes a good case *for* IIFE's: the scope gives you plenty of time to assign any object to a variable, so regardless of *How* you create a method (with or without an IIFE), you don't have to worry about what `this` references at any given time, just use the variables. 
You can implement some basic data hiding, too. In this example the initial value of `semiExposed` is being passed to an IIFE, and preserved within its scope. Nothing can muck this up (well, that's not *quite* true at the moment), so you can allways *revert* to the initial values of any property.

However, I will admit, IIFE's can make your code harder to read as it grows, and I completely understand why you'd *not* want to use them too much. You could look into `bind`, it'll help you cut back on many IIFE's, but there is a down-side. Some ppl still use IE8, for example, which doesn't support `bind`.
But an other option would be: create a simple IIFE *factory* function:

```
function giveScope(varsFromScope,toFunction)
{
    return function()
    {
        var passArguments = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments,[0]);//get args from call
        passArguments.push({scope:varsFromScope});
        toFunction.apply(this,passArguments);
    };
}
var pseudoClosure = giveScope({scopeContext: this, something:'else'},function(arg1,arg2)
    {
        //function body here
        arguments[arguments.length - 1].currentContext;//<== "closure scope"
        this;//called context
    });
```

That way, you can get rid of some IIFE's, by replacing them with a simple function call to which you pass an object. Easy, and X-browser compatible.

Lastly, your first snippet is something that I do tend to use in event delegation:

```
var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
var parentDiv = (function(targetRef)
{
    while(targetRef.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'div')
    {
        targetRef = targetRef.parentNode;
    }
    return targetRef;
}(target));
```

That way, I don't have to create another veriable in the same scope, my targetRef is assigned to `parentDiv` when the div is found, and targetRef is GC'ed, I'm finished with it, so there's no need for that variable to stay in scope.

It's getting rather late now, and I don't know if I'm making much sense at all. Bottom line is: You might *hate* IIFE's, but you can't really do without them.
If it's the mass of parentheses that bother you, you might be glad to know that you don't *have* to use them. Any operator that forces the JS engine to interpret the function declaration as an expression will do:

```
(function()
{
}());
//can be written as:
!function()
{
}();
//or
~function()
{
}();
//or when assigning the return value, you don't even need anything at all:
var foo = function()
{
    return 'bar';
}();
console.log(foo);//logs bar
```

Perhaps you prefer an alternative notations? But honestly: you may not *like* the syntax, but I'm afraid you're going to have to live with it, or switch to coffeescript or something.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear to me what you're aiming for.  Are you just looking for something like this?:

```
var ns = ns || {};
ns.Class = {
    Navigation: (function() {
        return $('#element').on('click', function() {alert('element clicked');});
    })()
};
```

Here the handler has been attached and `ns.Class.Navigation` is a reference to the jQuery wrapper around `#element`.  If you don't need that reference, then why are you assigning anything to the (otherwise empty) result of calling that immediately invoked function expression?  `ns.Class` is not a function, but it didn't look as though you were actually using it as a function.

Does this do what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah that looks good. The reason I assigned `nothing` to ns.Class was simply because in my method, without Class, I couldn't get to `navigation`.

Comment: are you saying that using the `Object Literal` pattern might work better in this case over using the `Module` pattern?

Comment: Also, from what I can tell in this situation, the jQuery is called with or without the `return`. What is the return doing in this case?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: I like the `return` statment: creating a function that uses methods of another lib _should_ return whatever the lib returns, even if that return value is undefined. in this case, it returns a reference to `$('#element')`, so you can chain a couple of methods on there without having to use another selector, and scan the dom multiple times

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: as Elias said, it simply returns the jQuery wrapper object.  Without it, `ns.Class.Navigation` is simply `undefined`, which might be fine, but then why bother having such a property?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: regarding the pattern, I'm really not concerned about what you call it.  For this simple case, there is certainly no reason to add additional function wrappers.  If you have additional features that you want various functions inside `ns.Class` to have access to, but which you don't want publicly available, then you might need another function at that level, presumably an immediately invoked function expression.  But start simple, and only add it if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function ns() {
    "use strict";
    (function Class(){
        alert('ns.Class fired');
    }());
});
```

ns is being passed to jquery object,and invocation occurs within function parens - passes the crockford test (jslint).

Answer (score 0):

```
const outerName = (function innerFunc() {
  // Private stuff executed once on creation.
  const createdOnce = document.createElement('textarea');

  return function returnedFunc(someArg1, someArg2) {
    console.log('Hi!');
  };
}());
```